# Arduino equivalent to Java parseLong

Tags: java, c++, arduino

I am trying to write this Java code:

```
Long.parseLong(dev_key.substring(0, 8),16);
```

in Arduino code. I've found that the parseLong equivalent in Arduino is `atol(dev_key.substring(0, 8));`, but what about the second parameter of `parseLong`? The [definition](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-long-parselong-method) of that second parameter is `The radix that is used during parsing` so how would I write that in Arduino code? What does the radix mean?

Comment: There's stol: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stol/

Comment: Try strtol instead.   It has the option for a base.